# Hexo deployment in github get stuck after generate

Tags: github, deployment, hexo

I could not deploy my hexo to github after I put in `hexo deploy` .

It will creat many files in .deploy folder, but then the shell window will get stuck .

I do not know what is the problem.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Could you add the error message generated by hexo please?

Follow this step, it should work:
1. Install [hexo-deployer-git](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-deployer-git) with `npm install hexo-deployer-git --save`
2. Edit In your hexo `_config.yml` (not the `_config.yml`of your theme) :

```
deploy:
    type: git
    repo: <repository url>
    branch: [branch]
    message: [message]
```

3. Run `hexo clean`
4. Run `hexo generate --deploy`